# Gradient Descent over $f(x)=\frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i^2$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, recursive-algorithms, gradient-descent, gradient-flows

Consider the quadratic function:
$$
f(x) := \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i^2
$$
where $x, a \in \mathbb{R}^d$. According to [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) w.r.t.
$x$, we update as follows:
$$
x^{(k+1)} := x^{(k)} - t \nabla f(x^{(k)})
$$
With $t$ being the step size. Therefore,
$$
x^{(k+1)}_i = (1- t a_i) x_i^{(k)}
$$
Implying that
$$
x_{i}^{(k)} = (1-t a_i)^{k} x_i^{(0)}
$$
Now assume that $t |a_i| < 1$ for all $i$, and there exists exactly one $i$ s.t.
$a_i < 0$. According to this [source](http://www.offconvex.org/2016/03/24/saddles-again/), it holds that:

> The function diverges to negative infinity exponentially quickly from any randomly chosen starting point.

My question is: What exactly does it mean that ‘The function diverges to negative infinity’?

Comment: If $x \to \infty$, where does $x \mapsto -x^2$ diverge to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is wrong . In the source context, he means if a single $a_i$ is negative,
then the algorithm will let $x_j^k \to 0 ,\, j\not = i$ except the $x_i^k \to \infty ,as \,k\to \infty$ , then the value of function $f_k = \frac 12 a_i(x_i^k)^2\to-\infty$ because $a_i $ is negative